# Standard visitor visa for plab2 exam

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I'm wondering if my friend who is a British citizen can be my sponsor for the trip. I'm a working doctor and I live with my family members my two sisters and the their siblings who are 3.both my sisters are divorced and I'm supporting my family financially. I have a regular job but I'm not able to save for the trip. I managed to pay the fees  for plab2 and the plane ticket. My friend will provide the accommodation for me and he will take care of my all dialy expenses for the intended period which is 30 days. We are close friend. We went to the same university and spent most of the time together  and I  have visited and stayed with him regulary in our home country. We have shared memories together and pictures. Do I have any chance of being granted the visa

Comment: Anything can happen. I’ve seen more hopeless cases succeed. That said your chances appear very slim.

Comment: The above question contains lots of information that's specifically relevant to PLAB applications. The question is mostly intended for people who have had a visa application rejected but knowing that information in advance will surely be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately you have already made a mistake: The UK visa guidance is very clear that you should not pay for flights until after you receive a visa. If you have purchased flights already, this reduces your chance of receiving a visa.

Comment: @Saber abdalla Your question implies you’ve already booked your flight, however the Supporting Documents guide specifically states that proof of flight bookings is not required https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf